# Do Venom Hydra pools stack?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

The Venom Hydra Rune does the following:

> Summon a poison breathing Hydra that leaves a pool of acid that causes 18% weapon damage per second as Poison to enemies who remain in the pool.

Does the damage from these pools stack if a monster is in 2 overlapping pools at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In fact, the pools can overlap also. So an enemy standing still can get hit by the 3 heads at once, and be taking 18% x3 damage per second. They also last for a time, so they can stack again.